# Sum the factors of a number (excluding the number itself)

Tags: python

After I edited my code, I understand how to do it:

```
def sum_factors(n):
  sum = 0
  factor = 1
  # Return the sum of all factors of n, not including n
  while n!=0 and factor < n:
    if n % factor == 0:
        sum = sum + factor
        factor = factor + 1
    else:
        factor = factor + 1
  return sum
```

My initial code could not sum the factors but I don't understand why:

```
def sum_divisors(n):
  sum = 0
  factor = 1
  # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
  while n % factor == 0 and factor < n:
    sum = sum + factor
    factor = factor + 1
  return sum
```

Could you please explain why my initial code didn't work?

Comment: The `while` loop will exit the first time `n % factor` is not equal to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop writes

```
while n % factor == 0 and factor < n:
```

This would mean that once n % factor test condition is false, the code will break out of the while loop.

Let's use 10 as an example.

10 % 1 equals zero and 10 % 2 equals 0. But 10 % 3 does not equal 0. This means we break out of the while loop once factor gets to 3.

The answer we get would then be the sum of 1 and 2 which would be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The initial code put a strong emphasize on the condition `while n % factor == 0` which is not a necessary condition to end the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it helps to add some debugging output to a Python program:

```py
def sum_divisors(n):
    sum = 0
    factor = 1
    # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
    print(f"factor = {factor}")
    while n % factor == 0 and factor < n:
        sum = sum + factor
        factor = factor + 1
        print(f"factor = {factor}")
    return sum

print(sum_divisors(30))
```

**Output**

```
factor = 1
factor = 2
factor = 3
factor = 4
6
```

**Notes**

As we can see, the while loop exits when it finds a number that is not a factor.

**Refactoring**

I noticed that you have duplicate code in your `if-else` block. Whenever this happens, you can move the common code outside:

```py
    if n % factor == 0:
        sum = sum + factor
    factor = factor + 1
```